# What should I do to move a sprite randomly between two specific placements?

Tags: mit-scratch

What should I do to move a sprite randomly between two specific placements.
**For example, how can I implement this:**
***If direction = 90

Then, got to x:10 y:20 or x:30 y:50***
(I have just started using scratch and have no coding experience so I won't be able to understand any code.)

Answer (score 1):

Supplementary to [Mithrandir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4946380/mithrandir)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55478439/10876117):

If you don't want to use a variable, you can do it like this:

This solution is basically the same but saves a little bit of time and space if you don't need to use the `variable` anymore.

[image: Solution without using any variables]

Or, in pseudocode:

```
if (direction) = 90 then
  if {pick random (1) to (2)} = 1 then
    go to x: (10) y: (20)
  else
    go to x: (30) y: (50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can do it:

[image: transcript below]

```
if (direction) = 90 then
  set (variable) to {pick random (1) to (2)}
  if (variable) = 1 then
    go to x: (10) y: (20)
  else
    go to x: (30) y: (50)
```

The way this works is, when the trigger ((direction) = (90)) is met, we choose where to go by picking randomly between 1 and 2. The project then sets a variable to the value of the number picked. We can then use that value to decide which option gets picked. If the number 1 was picked, then go to one option; if it was the other (since there are no other options there's no need to out in an explicit IF (variable) = 2), go to the other spot.

Remember that you *will* need a hat block (a starting block) to start the script, though, such as WHEN GREEN FLAG CLICKED. Also note that if you just use an IF block immediately after a hat block, the script will just check it once immediately after the project starts. If you want this to happen in the middle of the project, wrapping this whole thing inside a FOREVER block might be a good thing to do.